# how to setup multiple repos in existing react js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application which has 3 main features like student, teacher and school.
everything is placed in single repo on develop branch.

I want to implement the feature of multi repos for each feature of the react application into independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with [lerna-bootstrap][1]

you can visit the link above and get full documentation on how to do that
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lerna/bootstrap

Comment: do we have any other option than this? 
or do we have any setup of lerna npm?

Comment: https://medium.com/@jeffkhull/a-typescript-monorepo-without-lerna-7805920c370f